# Translate whole component via i18n in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-i18n

I want to translate my whole component with i18n and I don't know how to use $t() in this use case. I have data like this

```
[
{"prizeCount":"300","prizeSum":"2442000","gameStartAt":"2018-01-08 13:00:00.000000"},       
  {"prizeCount":"288","prizeSum":"2530000","gameStartAt":"2018-01-09 12:00:00.000000"}
]
```

I pass this data to `:items="mydata"` for table and I want to translate title of my fields for example I want to translate prizeCount to another language.
I am using `vue-bootstrap`.
What is the best solution for this?

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import i18n from './i18n'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,

  components: {
    App
  },

  i18n,
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Comment: Can you provide `main.js` or `app.js` where you import `i18n`? @sinak

Comment: @mare96 post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,

  components: {
    App
  },

  i18n,
  t: i18n.t,
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Than in your component you can use `$t` or `this.$t` in your methods.

For get keys from your object you can do like this:

```
data: [
 {"prizeCount":"300","prizeSum":"2442000","gameStartAt":"2018-01-08 13:00:00"},       
 {"prizeCount":"288","prizeSum":"2530000","gameStartAt":"2018-01-09 12:00:00"}
]

data.forEach( obj => {
  let keys = Object.keys(obj)
  // ['prizeCount', 'prizeSum', 'gameStartAt']
  newData = []
  newObj = {}
  keys.forEach( key => {
    let val = obj[key]
    let trans = this.$t(key)
    newObj[trans] = val
  })

  newData.push(newObj)
})
```

Comment: cant use $(t) stuff in this use case. how can i use this??what is code like

Comment: You can use it like `$t('hello')`, hello is variable in your translate file. You are not clear what do you need? You need to translate your data keys before displaying it.

Comment: In your case only you can do if you pass data like this is to get keys from object and translate keys before send it to table.

Comment: Check edit. Maybe you can do something like this. I didn't test it but it's good idea. Good luck.